# Can I get the total length of an rle object without using inverse?

Tags: r, run-length-encoding

Let us say I have a Rle like so, of length 10:

```
b = rle(c("H", "T", "T", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "T", "H"))
```

How can I get the length of this object without using `inverse.rle`?

```
length(inverse.rle(b))
# 10
```

I have some sparse Rles representing chromosomes and they can have a length of hundreds of millions so I would rather not use inverse.

---

akruns answer does not work on my data:

```
> a
$ mydata
numeric-Rle of length 57442693 with 12471 runs
  Lengths: 2709826     100   31062     100 ...       2     232     100      47
  Values :       0       1       0       1 ...       1       0       1       0

> a$lengths
NULL
```

Comment: Ah, there is both an rle and an Rle object. Getting further....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the `rle` is a `list` object with `lengths` and `values` as elements of the `list`, we can extract the `lengths` and `sum`

```
sum(b$lengths)
#[1] 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your edit: akrun’s answer *still* generally works, you just need to adapt it slightly to your `Rle` data type:

I don’t know what function you’re using here but in case this is anything like the Bioconductor `Rle` S4 class, the solution would be

```
sum(s@lengths)
```

That is, instead of the nested name `lengths` you have to use the S4 slot name `lengths`. More generally, you can find out which solution works by inspecting:

1. The object names via `names(obj)`.
2. Or, in the case of an S4 object, its slot names: `slotNames(obj)`.

Answer (score 2):

For the `S4vectors` class `Rle` you need to use the method `runLength`, it has no accessor `$length`.

In my example above, this becomes `runLength(a[[1]])`.

Comment: For any other R noobs ending up here, `sum(runLength(a[[1]]))` works for me, but also `sum(a$peak1@lengths)` and `sum(a[1]$peak1@lengths)` work if you want to use the name (which in my case is `peak1`..`peakn`). I get the same exact result. Of course, your names must be unique.